# What small parts should I be mindful of when buying a frameset?

Tags: frames, parts, build

I have a project of building a touring bike from scratch by cherry picking every component. I started looking at some potential framesets.

One of the candidates is the [Surly Disc Trucker](https://surlybikes.com/bikes/disc_trucker). I can see on the product page that they propose a build kit for it, listing all the major components, but they seem to omit the required *small parts* that may not be included with the frameset. For example, is the cable guide under the bottom bracket (e.g. [Shimano SM-SP18](https://bike.shimano.com/en-US/product/service-upgradeparts/shimano/WP-Y66Y98600.html)) included? What about the bolts, axles, collars, etc?

So, in a general way since I have not settled on a specific frameset yet (and also specifically for the Disc Trucker since I consider it seriously), what small parts are usually overlooked when buying a frameset? That would be a shame to order it and all the components just to realize that a small part is missing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd say the four most important parts are:

1. For frames supporting installation of downtube shifters, the cable stops that attach to the downtube bosses
2. For frames having under-bottom-bracket cable routing, the cable guide
3. Seatpost collar
4. Thru-axles should the frame and/or fork use ones

I can say that I have done what you did but before the era of disk brakes so the frame obviously was Surly Long Haul Trucker. It did come with a cable guide installed under the bottom bracket, but Shimano says that for optimal shifting you should use the Shimano cable guide so you might want to swap it for a genuine Shimano one.

It didn't come with downtube cable stops, though. It came with a seatpost collar, but not a good one so I used a Surly Constrictor instead of the original collar.

Answer (score 4):

When I built up a new frame from parts, my frame (not a Surly) came with most of the small pieces I needed.

Headset: If the Surly does not come with a headset, be aware that there are a few different headset standards, and you'll need the right one. Surlies all use traditional pressed-in cups, near as I can tell.

Bottom bracket: there are numerous standards for bottom brackets too. I think Surlies use plain-old ISO/British BBs.

Disk brakes: Surly uses flat-mount brakes, which are common on road bikes. You'll need mounting bolts of the correct length in the rear. You can get away with plain-old bolts, but there are special bolts for disk brakes that have a recess for a cotter pin as a failsafe. These bolts come in 4 different lengths for the rear brake (based on the depth of the mounting bosses). You may also need mounting plates.

Also remember to get your head tube, bottom bracket, and brake mounts faced before you start installing parts.

Comment: Is facing always required for a new frame or it is on a case-by-case basis?

Comment: I’d say it’s always a good idea  unless you know for certain it was faced by the factory.